# Circular buffer Vs. Lock free stack to implement a Free List

Tags: c, stack, lock-free, circular-buffer

As I have been writing some multi-threaded code for fun, I came up with the following situation:

a thread claims a single resource unit from a memory pool, it processes it and sends a pointer to this data to another thread for further operation using a circular buffer (1R / 1W case).

The latter must inform the former thread whenever it is done with the data he received, so that the memory can be recycled.

I wonder whether it is better - performance-wise - to implement this "Freelist" as another circular buffer - holding  the addresses of free resources - or choose the lock-free stack way (implementing DCAS on x86-64).

Generally speaking, what could be the pros and the cons of the two different approaches ?

Comment: 'The latter must inform the former thread whenever it is done with the data he received, so that the memory can be recycled' - why?  Why cannot the consumer thread recycle the instance/struct/whatever to the pool itself?  Why should the producer thread have to do it?  If there is more than one pool, (eg. if each producer has its own pool), you can pass the pool instance/func-pointer/whatever in the struct/instance/whatever, (honestly, this sort of stuff is much, much easier in an OO language, plus us developers then don't have to type long 'struct/instance/pointer' strings into comments).

Comment: I am flexible on this: when I wrote the question, I had in mind a model where the two threads communicates forth and back using two circular buffers. Nothing prevents to switch to a model where they both operate on the memory pool.
I am just interested on the pros and cons of the two approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case, there is a difference between lock-free and wait-free. The former means there is no locking but the thread can still busy-spin not making any progress. The latter means that the thread always makes progress with no locking or busy-spinning.

With one reader and one writer lock-free and wait-free FIFO circular buffer is trivial to implement.

I hear that LIFO stack can also be made wait-free, but not so sure about FIFO list. And it sound like you need a queue here rather then a stack.

Comment: the order of data insertion is not really important, I picked the stack because it should be easier to manage. Still, I prefer to deal with circular buffers whenever it is possible but I'm collecting ideas.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is the circular buffer will be bounded, while the stack will not.

It's hard to make a performance judgement on things like this without testing.  On the one hand, the circular buffer is backed by a contiguous array.  If the reader and writer indices remain "near" each other, you'll have each thread constantly invalidating a shared cache line.

On the other hand, with a stack you can have contention for the top-of-stack pointer, resulting in threads sometimes spinning in the CAS loop.

My guess would be that the best choice is workload-dependent.